# How can I convert/format a value returned from a jquery to a razor?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have this line in my View

```
<h1 > Reply to: @Model.dialogueEntity[index].DialogueSubject</h1>
```

and I am trying to get the value of the button clicked to change the value of the index (I have a for loop that assigns a value for each one of the buttons). I was able to print it as text by using the following line

```
<h1 id="lastClicked">test</h1>
```

How can I put the value returned from the jquery in the [index] part of the code?

Here is my jquery click part

```
          $(".reply-button")
          .click(function(e) 
            {
                var target = $(e.target);
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#lastClicked').text( target.attr('value')  );
                $('#index').val( target.attr('value')  );
                $('#Window').data('tWindow').center().open();

            }
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a no brainer jquery question. I just started learning about it.

edit: Here is the code for my button code. Remember: it is inside a for loop

```
 <button id="Reply-open-button-@i" class="t-button t-state-default reply-button" value = "@i">Reply</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get any code which C# used in your client-side javascript.

However, you can use the `data-*` attribute to store the index in the element itself, then retrieve that when needed. Try this:

```
<h1 data-index="@index">Reply to: @Model.dialogueEntity[index].DialogueSubject</h1>
```

```javascript
 $element.click(function(e) {
      var index = $(this).data("index");
      // the rest of your code...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error under data-index saying "the attribute 'data-index' is not a valid attribute  of <h1>.

Comment: I found a work around by sending the info to the controller. There is no other way it seems. Thanks